# Equating Coefficients of Cos and Sin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I've got a nonlinear system
\begin{align}
x'&=\frac{1}{2}x-y-\frac{1}{2}(x^3+y^2x)\\
y'&=x+\frac{1}{2}y-\frac{1}{2}(y^3+x^2y)
\end{align}

I am to analyse the system when the system is changed to polar coordinates. The writer of the book states that he computes the following
\begin{align}
r'\cos\theta-r(\sin\theta)\theta'&=x'=\frac{1}{2}(r-r^3)\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\\
r'\sin\theta+r(\cos\theta)\theta'&=y'=\frac{1}{2}(r-r^3)\sin\theta+r\cos\theta
\end{align}

And by equating the coefficients of $\cos\theta,\sin\theta$ he gets the following system
\begin{align}
r'&=r(1-r^2)/2\\
\theta'&=1
\end{align}

My issues is then:

I'm not sure where he gets the following identities
\begin{align}
r'\cos\theta-r(\sin\theta)\theta'&=x'\\
r'\sin\theta+r(\cos\theta)\theta'&=y'
\end{align}

And I'm not that familiar with the equating coefficients method, so I've read a bit about it, and I can't seem to compute the presented system.

If I were to make a phase portrait of the system, would the axis be $r'$ and $\theta'$?

Source: [c. 8, p. 162], Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems & An Introduction to Chaos (2nd Ed) by Morris W. Hirsch, Stephen Smale and Robert L. Devaney.

Comment: @Moo That is what the book states. Do you get another system?

Comment: Can you explain your procedure? And how he get the identities he uses for equating the coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\theta) \\
y=r\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}\qquad
\begin{cases}
x'=r'\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)\theta' \\
y'=r'\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)\theta' 
\end{cases}
$$
$$\begin{cases}
x'=r'\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)\theta'=\frac12r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)-\frac12r^3\cos(\theta) \\
y'=r'\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)\theta'=r\cos(\theta)+\frac12 r\sin(\theta)-\frac12r^3\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
$$

$x'\cos(\theta)+y'\sin(\theta)=r'=\left(\frac12r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)-\frac12r^3\cos(\theta) \right)\cos(\theta)+\left(r\cos(\theta)+\frac12 r\sin(\theta)-\frac12r^3\sin(\theta) \right)\sin(\theta)$

and after simplification :
$$r'=\frac12r-\frac12r^3$$

$-x'\sin(\theta)+y'\cos(\theta)=r\theta' =-\left(\frac12r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)-\frac12r^3\cos(\theta) \right)\sin(\theta)+\left(r\cos(\theta)+\frac12 r\sin(\theta)-\frac12r^3\sin(\theta) \right)\cos(\theta)$

and after simplification :

$$r\theta'=r\qquad;\qquad \theta'=1$$

The equations in the book are correct.

Comment: It took me a few hours to figure it out. But i got through it. I get the same result for $r'=\frac{1}{2}(r-r^3)$ when i isolate $\theta'$ for $x',y'$ and set them as equal, with some additional calculations i get the desired result. 
$\theta'=1$ i get with same procedure although i just isolate for $r$ in $x',y'$. 

I get the same system, although my intuition behind it is vaguely logical, and the calculations took quite a bit time! Thanks a lot! 

Best Regards 
Jens

Answer (score 1):

He differentiates $x=r\cos\theta$ with the product rule.
Then multiply the third equation by $\cos\theta$, plus multiply the fourth equation by $\sin\theta$.  That eliminates the $\theta^\prime$ terms.

Answer (score 0):

Or one can set $z=x+iy$, then
$$
z'=(\tfrac12+i)z-\tfrac12z|z|^2=\tfrac12(1+2i-|z|^2)z
$$
so that for radius and angle one gets
\begin{alignat}1
\frac{d}{dt}|z|^2&=2Re(\bar zz')&&=(1-|z|^2)|z|^2\\
\frac{d}{dt}\arg(z)&=Im(\frac{z'}{z})&&=1
\end{alignat}

Answer (score 0):

While the method in the book is correct, it is often easier to derive the polar coordinates version using
\begin{align}
rr'&=xx'+yy'\\
r^2\theta'&=xy'-yx'
\end{align}
which is obtained by differentiating
$$
r^2=x^2+y^2,\quad\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}.
$$
Indeed, the $r'$-equation is clear, and differentiating $\tan\theta=y/x$ gives
$$
(\tan\theta)'=\theta'\sec^2\theta=\theta'(1+\tan^2\theta)=\theta'\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}=r^2\theta'
$$
in the LHS and
$$
\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'=\frac{xy'-yx'}{x^2}
$$
in the RHS.